# Auto Increment in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to set an auto_increment just like you would in MySQL for Neo4j? For example, I want nodes to start with numbers like 1000000000 when I create them with the GraphDatabaseService object. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using the Java lib directly or are you going through the REST API?

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this answer: [Can I create a node in neo4j with specified id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626470/can-i-create-a-node-in-neo4j-with-specified-id)

The ID that Neo4J assigns each object different than the PK assigned to a row in a database.  the location in the Node index is reflected in the ID that Neo4J assigns.  In a Relational Database the value is simply a unique and indexed key that you can look up against. A cleaner approach would be to create a arbitrary Index value as a Node property and Index it (so you can do quick look ups against it).