# How to implement auto-increment id property of label in neo4jphp?

Tags: php, neo4j, auto-increment, neo4jphp

I have to create schema such that there will be property "id" for label "City".
I have to make autoincrement value of "id" on every node I create of label type "City". I am using PHP library of neo4j:[neo4jphp](/questions/tagged/neo4jphp)

I have seen this task [Auto Increment in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11836838/1045444) but it is not having way given to do by php or specific strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an [unmanaged extension](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) in Java (or other JVM language) that uses a [TransactionEventHandler](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.2/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html) to manage counters and deploy it to your Neo4j server.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't technically what you asked for (since it isn't an auto-increment or numeric) since neo4j doesn't have an auto-increment...  but this is how I solved the same problem by generating a randomized string as an ID

change `$length` if you want a different default length, `$tries` is just used to prevent an infinite loop... (this function tries to create a unique ID of 5 length 3 times, then tries to create 6 long id etc...

```
function makeNewID($client, $length = 5, $trys = 0)
   {
      //chars to pick from
      $charlist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
      $strlen = strlen($charlist)-1;

      //alpha numeric generated in this for statement
      for ($newID = '', $i = 0; $i < $length; $newID .= $charlist[mt_rand(0, $strlen)], ++$i);
      //query the database to see if the 'new id exists'
      $query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, 'MATCH (n{id:"'.$newID.'"}) RETURN n.id LIMIT 1');
      $result = $query->getResultSet();
      if(!empty($result[0]['x']->getProperty('id')))
      {
        $trys++;
        if($trys >= 3){$length++; $trys = 0;}
        $newID = makeNewID($Neo, $length, $trys);
      }
      return $newID;
   }
```

PS. I removed the abstraction layer in my code and replaced it with the actual neo4jphp lib's code, but i haven't tested it.